# Iterate and modify the data of boost::multiindex

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include "modify_example.hpp"

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

namespace{

struct name{};
struct email{};

struct employee
{
    std::string email_;
    std::string name_;

    employee(std::string name, std::string email) :
        email_(email),
        name_(name)
    {}
};

using DispatchUsersTable =
multi_index_container
<
  employee,
  indexed_by
  <
    ordered_unique
    <
      tag<name>, member
      <employee, std::string, &employee::name_>
    >,
    ordered_unique
    <
      tag<email>, member
      <employee, std::string, &employee::email_>
    >
  >
>;

}

void order_after_modify()
{
    DispatchUsersTable table;
    table.insert(employee{"jk", "http:cat"});
    table.insert(employee{"otaku", "http:joker"});
    table.insert(employee{"cba", "http:amota"});

    //auto will make codes much easier to read
    //I type the type explicitly because I need to
    //maintain the codes created by c++98
    using Table = DispatchUsersTable::index<name>::type;
    using Iterator = Table::iterator;

    std::vector<std::string> names{"doremi", "onpu", "aichan"};
    size_t num = 0;
    for(Iterator it = table.get<name>().begin();
        it != table.get<name>().end(); ){
        std::cout<<it->name_<<", "<<it->email_<<std::endl;
        name_index.modify(it++, [&](employee &e){ e.name_ = names[num++]; });
    }            
}
```

I would like to modify all of the contents of the multi_index by the for loop
but the codes cannot work properly(random behavior), I think I do not get the correct iterator when I combine the modify operation and itearation together. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: I find it highly ironic that you comment _`I type the type explicitly because I need to maintain the codes created by c++98`_ exactly before you use... template aliases instead of typedefs. These happen to be a c++11 feature implemented late in some compilers.

Comment: @ sehe What I need is the explicit type, this could help me reuse the codes in c++98 project.auto will hide the types related to the multi-index, but using and lambda do not hide them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `modify` changes the order of elements along the way, so iteration can revisit or skip past elements in a fairly unpredictable way. The solution is to store the iterators before doing the modification:

```
void order_after_modify()
{
    DispatchUsersTable table;
    table.insert(employee{"jk", "http:cat"});
    table.insert(employee{"otaku", "http:joker"});
    table.insert(employee{"cba", "http:amota"});

    //auto will make codes much easier to read
    //I type the type explicitly because I need to
    //maintain the codes created by c++98
    using Table = DispatchUsersTable::index<name>::type;
    using Iterator = Table::iterator;

    Table& name_index= table.get<name>();

    std::vector<std::string> names{"onpu", "doremi", "aichan"};

    std::vector<Iterator> view;
    for(Iterator it = table.get<name>().begin();it != table.get<name>().end(); ++it){
      view.push_back(it);
    }

    for(size_t num = 0;num<view.size();++num){
       std::cout<<view[num]->name_<<", "<<view[num]->email_<<std::endl;
       name_index.modify(view[num], [&](employee &e){ e.name_ = names[num]; });
    }            
}
```

Comment: in your answer you store iterators for index name....then you modify elements of same index name....this leads to changing of order of elements of index name...so how when you use the stored iterators, you get the elements without repetition or skip???is not iterator like pointer which points to address of certain element???or is it considered a reference which is alias of certain element??should i make this question??

Comment: `multi_index_container` is *stable*, meaning that iterators remain valid even if new elements are inserted or reordering happens. So, by storing all iterators within the range prior to modification we ensure we'll visit all the elements once and only once. Note that these iterators can be *repositioned* during the process, but we're not incrementing/decremeting them, just dereferencing to the elements.